# SPARQL query does not give all the results that are on dbpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm executing this query in http://dbpedia.org/snorql/:

Query:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>        
PREFIX type: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT ?country_name ?population
WHERE {
    ?country a type:LandlockedCountries ;
             rdfs:label ?country_name ;
             prop:populationEstimate ?population .
}
```

The query looks for all land looked countries.

I don't understand why in the results there are not some countries which are classified on 
"/dbpedia.org/class/yago/LandlockedCountries". For example, Paraguay (/dbpedia.org/page/ParaguAy) is classified but does not appear in the query result set. Can somebody explain me why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are a small number of landlocked countries that do not have values for at least one of the `country_name` and `populationEstimate` properties. This is why they will not be returned in your query. If you run the following query, those countries will come up (those two attributes are set as `OPTIONAL`).

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>        
PREFIX type: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT ?country ?country_name ?population
WHERE {
    ?country a type:LandlockedCountries .
    OPTIONAL {?country rdfs:label ?country_name Filter(lang(?country_name) = 'en')} .
    OPTIONAL {?country prop:populationEstimate ?population} .
}
```

[run query](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=PREFIX%20rdfs%3a%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0APREFIX%20type%3a%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/class/yago/%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20prop%3a%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/property/%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20?country%20?country_name%20?population%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20?country%20a%20type%3aLandlockedCountries%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B?country%20rdfs%3alabel%20?country_name%20Filter%28lang%28?country_name%29%20=%20%27en%27%29%7D%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B?country%20prop%3apopulationEstimate%20?population%7D%20.%0D%0A%7D%20)

For (slightly) better results, since some countries seem to be duplicated with erroneous capitalization (e.g. *ParaguAy* and *Paraguay*),  the following query uses  `?country dcterms:subject category:Landlocked_countries` instead of the yago class.

[run query](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=PREFIX+rdfs%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E++++++++%0D%0APREFIX+type%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fclass%2Fyago%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+prop%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dcterms%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+category%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FCategory%3A%3E%0D%0ASELECT+%3Fcountry+%3Fcountry_name+%3Fpopulation%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A++++%3Fcountry+dcterms%3Asubject+category%3ALandlocked_countries+.%0D%0A++++OPTIONAL+%7B%3Fcountry+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Fcountry_name+Filter%28lang%28%3Fcountry_name%29+%3D+%27en%27%29%7D+.%0D%0A++++OPTIONAL+%7B%3Fcountry+prop%3ApopulationEstimate+%3Fpopulation%7D+.%0D%0A%7D+)

Comment: Thanks kr1, your answer was very useful.